# how to distinguish between three comboxes in a form using java?

Tags: java, event-handling, jcombobox

I've created a form with three JComboBoxes in it using MVC model.
my controller class is inherited from ItemListener

inside my form I have

```
createCombobox(mypane , "year");
createCombobox(mypane , "month");
createCombobox(mypane , "day");

private void createComboBox( Container container,String datatype)
    {
        JComboBox jcmb = new JComboBox();
        jcmb.addItemListener(listener);
        container.add(jcmb);
        switch(datatype.toLowerCase())
        {
            case "year":
                v_ctl.addYearsToCombobox(jcmb);
                break;
            case "month":
                v_ctl.addMonthsToCombobox(jcmb);
                break;
            case "day":
                v_ctl.addDaysToComboBox(jcmb);
                break;
        }
    }
```

inside controller I have something

```
public class ComboBoxItemListener implements ItemListener
{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {


        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)event.getSource();


        System.out.println(event.getSource().toString());

    }

}
```

so how can I understand which one is changed during runtime inside the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your createCombobox routine, add something like

```
jcmb.setName(dataType);
```

Then inside your controller, you could identify each of them by name:

```
comboBox.getName();
```

Simply make the names constants that you share between the classes that need the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setName(String name)` method from Component class.

btw. Java do not support String as case element. Instead of that you should use ComboBoxModel to provide the content to it.

```
protected void createComboBox(String name, CoboBoxModel model, ItemListener itemListener)
{
        JComboBox jcmb = new JComboBox(model);
         jcmb.setName(name);
         jcmb.addItemListener(listener);
        return jcmb;
}
```

Then this seams to be more convenient

```
container.add(createCombobox("day", model, listener));
```

Comment: Java 7 supports Strings in switches.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the selected item for a JComboxBox, you can do

```
String value = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

Ok, you can set a name for the combobox:

```
    switch(datatype.toLowerCase())
    {
        case "year":
            jcmb.setName("year");
            v_ctl.addYearsToCombobox(jcmb);
            break;
        case "month":
            jcmb.setName("month");
            v_ctl.addMonthsToCombobox(jcmb);
            break;
        case "day":
            jcmb.setName("jcmb");
            v_ctl.addDaysToComboBox(jcmb);
            break;
    }
```

In your listener:

```
    String changedComboBoxName = comboBox.getName();
```

Comment: since there are some similarity between 3 combobox's items like days index and month index I can't use this approach.